# Non-equal batteries discharge in parallel connection

Tags: batteries, parallel, ohms-law

My friend and I have an argument and I want to ask the community to say who is right and who is wrong in their beliefs, and explain it with formulas and laws (if possible).

We have two different Li-ion cells connected in parallel. Both cells are charged to 4.1V. We put a load of approximately 2A on them and wait for some time. Now when we remove the load and disconnect cells from each other, they have different end voltage. My friend says that during the load, one cell powers the load while the other powers the load AND the weaker cell. I say that the current starts to flow from the stronger to the weaker cell only after the load is removed. Who is right and who is wrong?

BTW initially I thought they would end up having the same end voltage, because the weaker cell voltage would drop more under the load and the stronger cell would give more current out of it. But it appears that the cells end up having different voltages.

Comment: Why not start with the simplest, non-trivial battery model which uses an internal series resistance and an appropriately sized capacitor to represent the state of charge? Imagine your load as another resistor and imagine that the two batteries do not have the same value for their internal resistors. What happens when you apply the load?

Comment: You say "two **different**...cells" which means that their ESR may also be different. I think we need to know about the ESR of both cells to determine the outcome.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson they are just different. One has a lower internal resistance, the other has a higher IR.

Comment: @jonk probably one capacitor would discharge faster than the other

Comment: "We have two different Li-ion cells connected in parallel" **stop right here, you are both wrong** because you should not be doing that to begin with.  Any unprovided details hinting at one situation or the other are irrelevant when hiding behind a great big **things you should not do**.

Comment: What you need to know is how the voltage across the load compares to the end voltages of the cells. You specified 4.1V and 2A, without values for the ESR we can't answer your question. And where did "one capacitor" come from?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah. But their question seems more like an *experimental inquiry* one to me. Experiments aren't necessarily good practice (nor necessarily safe -- I can't even begin to count the number of experiments I've been involved in where there were significant risks.) But they can be educational.

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko Yes. And also now think about what your voltmeter would measure ***while*** they are both powering the load resistor and then what the voltmeter would measure once you have ***removed*** both supplies from each other and the load.

Comment: @jonk for me when they are connected the voltage is the same because there is no difference of potentials (average voltage of two?). When we disconnect everything two capacitors measure different voltage. Correct?

Comment: @ChrisStratton you just want to stop us understanding the physics of the process thus stopping the education. We are not making a device out of different cells. It's a science experiment.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson numbers were given just for reference. Get any two different Li-Ion cells and any load. It doesn't matter much here in my question

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko but it all comes down to what makes one of the cells weaker. Does it have less mAh capacity, more ESR due to internal structure or thinner wires or what. If you have a battery with large mAh but high ESR and a small battery with low ESR? And you are arguing about different things after all.

Comment: @DmytroLeonenko - this experiment is **unsafe** to conduct.  Further your question is unanswerable, because what would actually happen depends on details not provided and not realistically knowable by you.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not asking what would happen. The question is theoretical. To answer it one doesn't need to know exact numbers. There is nothing unsafe about discharging different cells on stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> initially I thought they would end up having the same end voltage,
>   because the weaker cell voltage would drop more under the load and the
>   stronger cell would give more current out of it. But it appears that
>   the cells end up having different voltages.

It depends on what is making one cell 'weaker'. Imagine cutting a single cell into two sections, one twice the size of the other. The 'weaker' section has 1/2 the capacity and 2 times the resistance of the 'stronger' section, but when both sections are joined together they act exactly like the complete cell - both discharging at the same rate and ending up with the same voltage.

However if you parallel two cells which have the same capacity but different resistances, the 'weaker' cell will discharge slower and end up with higher open-circuit voltage. On the other hand if both cells have equal resistances but one has lower capacity then it will discharge faster (relative to its capacity) and end up with lower open-circuit voltage.

In practice this means that cells should not be wired in parallel unless they have proportionally matched capacities and resistances, otherwise the 'stronger' cell will discharge more than the 'weaker' one and the expected battery capacity will not be realized. However this is really only a problem at high currents where internal resistances become significant.

Comment: I like your answer much more than others in my question. One thing I'd like to ask you to add is about what happens when the load removed? Our "weaker" (no matter because of capacity or IR) cell would effectively charge the stronger cell? I conducted an experiment with the power bank and two different cells in parallel. Discharged then for 20min using 5V2A load. In the end one cell was 0.12V higher than the other and I measured the current between them to be aprox 0.4-0.6A

Comment: If the 'weaker' cell has higher voltage (due to higher capacity*IR) it will charge the 'stronger' one. Charging current will be less than the discharge current from the weaker cell, and will taper off as the other cell charges, so It shouldn't be a problem unless the weaker cell has much higher capacity and the discharge current was high.  What was the rated capacity and maximum charging current of your cells?

Comment: They were Samsung 18650 ICR 26F (stronger) and Panasonic NCR18650B.

Comment: Same size cells, but the Panasonic has higher capacity so I would expect it to have higher resistance due to thinner plates. The Samsung cell is rated for 2.8A 'fast' charging current, so if you keep the discharge current below 2.8A it should be safe (though not good design practice).

Answer (score 3):

The circuit obeys Ohm's law at all times, so during any two batteries connected together, when initially both batteries are charged to same voltage, there is no current between them. When connected to a load, they both discharge to load via their ESR. As the current through ESR depends on voltage at the load and voltage at the cell, the cell can never discharge to lower than voltage at the load, so during the time when load is connected, no cell charges the other one. When disconnected from load, there are two different cell voltages connected via ESRs, so in this case higher voltage will charge the lower voltage. Feel free to simulate or calculate which battery charges which, depending on their capacity and ESR, as Q=I*t=C*U. If ESRs match, the lower capacity battery has less voltage and gets charged after removing load. If batteries have same capacity, the one with lower ESR has less voltage after removing load as it gave out more charge. In real world though, the battery chemistries and other behaviour of the batteries won't match so it depends on other things than capacity and ESR as well.

Comment: This breaks once you imagine a load that high pulse demands intermixed with a lower average...

Comment: Indeed it would and thus needs simulation. The original question did have just single 2A DC load attached for "some time", I tried to answer that.

Comment: I like your reply as well as @bruce-abbott. Load and voltage don't matter much to me in this question. It's more of a theoretical question and not something I try to assemble and thus want a calculation. I was interested in why the cell with lower IR and lower capacity would finish with a lower voltage. Now I understand why. Also now I know than the current between the cells would only flow after removing the load